# Grails GORM - return count of objects who's array property > 0

Tags: database, grails, hql, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

Consider the following;

```
class Person {
    int id
    String name

    static hasMany = [cars : Car]
}

class Car {
   int id
   String brand

   static belongsTo = Person
   static hasMany = [owners: Person]
}
```

The above will result in a `person_cars` join table. All I'm trying to find out is if there are any entries in that table, in words;

Do any Persons currently exist who own a car.

Happy to use any mechanism available (finders/criteria/HQL etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! A lot simpler than I thought.

```
 Person.createCriteria().count {
   owners {
     count
   }
 }
```

This effectively gives me the number of person_cars records.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is better to add PersonCar entity.

For your question:

```
Car.count() > 0
```

As car belongTo Person, so that can't be any copy of car without been added to the person.
If person is nullable you can use:

```
Car.countByPersonIsNotNull()
```

Think that if car has person, so that there will be a value in that table.

Comment: I thought your solution was going to work, but unfortunately it doesn't when I test it. I get returned a count of whatever number of Cars exist in the database.
I'll add PersonCar if absolutely necessary but was hoping I could find a means to achieve this single requirement without it.

Comment: If you received Car that meant that you have a data in the person_cars